# create multiple new dataframes based on an existing data frames column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame, `df`, that has 4 columns and a lot of rows.

I want to create 5 different data frames based on the value of one of the columns of the data frame. The column I am referring to is called `color`.

`color` has 5 unique values: `red`, `blue`, `green`, `yellow`, `orange`.

What I want to do is each of the 5 new data frames should contain all rows which have on of the values in `color`. For instance `df_blue` should have all the rows and columns where in the other data frame the value from the `color` column is blue.

The code I have is the following:

```
# create 5 new data frames
df_red = []
df_blue= []
df_green= []
df_yellow= []
df_orange= []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['color'] == "blue"
       df_blue.append(df)

# i would do if-else statements to satisfy all 5 colors
```

I feel I am missing some logic...any suggestions or comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `groupby`. The following code fragment creates a sample DataFrame and converts it into a dictionary where colors are keys and the matching dataframes are values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red','blue','red','green','blue'],
                   'foo': [1,2,3,4,5]})
colors = {color: dfc for color,dfc in df.groupby('color')}
#{'blue':   color  foo
#         1  blue    2
#         4  blue    5, 
# 'green':    color  foo
#          3  green    4, 
# 'red':   color  foo
#        0   red    1
#        2   red    3}
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehension nice. +1

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'groupby'`, also how can I do using data frames? I tried `data.groupby('color')` and it outputs `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000003193DF28>`. I want to have 5 data frames for each unique color.

Comment: You said `df` is a DataFrame. Why is it a `dict`?

Comment: oh, the first error that says `dict` is the output of putting this code `colors = {color: dfc for color,dfc in df.groupby('color')}`

Comment: the second error i mentioned was a result of this code `data.groupby('color')`

Comment: Yes, the result is a `dict` of several DataFrames (one per color). But the original data is in the DataFrame called `df`.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing this for each of the colors.

```
  blue_data = data[data.color =='blue']
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. You should use a dictionary for a variable number of variables.

Comment: It's inefficient, manual, hard to track, assumes you know your colours beforehand, prone to error, polluting the namespace, unstructured.

Comment: hmm i see...well my dataframe consists of pandas series, that is why i did it that way